# Suggestion for faster select query

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE `partially_allowed` (
  `service_area_code` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `number` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_type` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `preference` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `idx_number` (`number`(4))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

having 29,731,330 rows. I need to join this with another table

```
CREATE TABLE `data_from_files` (
  `mobile` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pin` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

having over 10,000,000 rows.

What is the best possible index for a fast select query?

Comment: Index  columns which you will use in `ON()` clause

Comment: The ON clause is on number and mobile columns. Both are VARCHAR. Will an in index of length 4 work? Or do I need to index the complete column? I am using length 4 because mobile numbers can be identified by their operators by the first 4 digits.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` command can help you optimize your tables: dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html –

Comment: I don't see a PRIMARY KEY !!! Also INT(1) does not mean what you think it means

Comment: Please show the query that you want to optimize.  Any query that returns tens of millions of rows (as your question suggests) is going to take a really, really long time just to return the data.

Comment: if you set up indexes correctly it wont take a very long time to execute a query. (currently i have one set up to return 2.5 million rows in less than a second)

Comment: @JohnRuddell: returning 2.5 million rows in less than a second seems hardly possible. Transferring the rows over the network will most probably take longer than that.